# Why I can't convert the objects into valid React children when declaring state in interface but it works when declaring state inside the class?

Tags: reactjs, json, object, state, children

I am trying to get some data from REST API in React v15.6.2 (needed version for sharepoint framework for on prem). Resposne is asigned to json object then saved to state and in render method I want to convert the objects into valid React children so that I can render id, name, phone ... etc

method 1: When state is declared before class it is not working and VS code underline the keys of my object with error "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'".

method 2: When state is declared inside the class it is working.

What is difference between these two ways of declaring state ?

code of method 1 (not working)

```
export interface IHelloWorldState{

  persons: []

}

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component < IHelloWorldProps, IHelloWorldState > {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind methods
    this.updateFullName = this.updateFullName.bind(this)
    this.updateAge = this.updateAge.bind(this)
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)

    this.state = {

      persons: []
      
    };

  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            
            this.setState({
              persons: data
            })
            console.log(typeof(data))
            
          });
        } else {
          response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
            console.log(responseJSON);
            alert(`Something went wrong! Check the error in the browser console.`);
          });
        }
        })
  
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return(

         <div className={styles.container}>
         <div>
            {this.state.persons.map(person => (
                <div key={person.name}>     // underlining name
                    <p>{person.name}</p>    // underlining name
                    
                </div>
            ))}
          
        </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
```

code of method 2 (works)

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component < IHelloWorldProps, {} > {
state = {
    
    person: []
}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind methods
    this.updateFullName = this.updateFullName.bind(this)
    this.updateAge = this.updateAge.bind(this)
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)

  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            
            this.setState({
              persons: data
            })
            console.log(typeof(data))
            
          });
        } else {
          response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
            console.log(responseJSON);
            alert(`Something went wrong! Check the error in the browser console.`);
          });
        }
        })
  
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return(

         <div className={styles.container}>
         <div>
            {this.state.persons.map(person => (
                <div key={person.name}>
                    <p>{person.name}</p>
                    
                </div>
            ))}
          
        </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
```

I expected the same behavior but not.

Comment: `persons: { name: string }[]`